# High Resolution Image Using Google Chart API

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I am using Google chart API to get a chart in image form via URL.

The URL I am passing in my 'img' tag is : https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=pc&chco=FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,74D3EF|EDEDED&chd=t:-1|-1|-1|-1|52,48&chs=122x122&chp=4.7

I am getting the image as I want, **just wanted to know if i can get a high resolution image ?**

Answer (score 1):

Set the "chs" parameter to the dimensions you want:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=pc&chco=FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,FFFFFF,74D3EF|EDEDED&chd=t:-1|-1|-1|-1|52,48&chs=500x500&chp=4.7

The ImageChart API supports images up to 30000 pixels total (eg, 500x600).  If you need a higher resolution chart, you will have to switch to another chart API (like the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index)).

Comment: What i think the chs parameter does is making the image bigger, what i want is an image of 122x122 but a lot more crisper and shud not pixelate on zooming, also it should look good on the new iPhone which will have retina display. If i m wrong plz let me know.

Comment: You can't get a sharper 122x122 pixel image.  What you want is a higher resolution image that is scaled down to fit whatever dimensions are appropriate.